# IIS Express sites not started from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

Some developers in my company work on a Visual Studio 2013 solution.
The solution includes the following ASP.NET web projects :

- Project : Espace

  - **StartUp Project**
  - **Start Page : TestFiles\Authentication.aspx**
  - Properties :

    - Development Server :

      - Always Start When Debugging : True
      - Anonymous Authentication : Enabled
      - Managed Pipeline Mode : Integrated
      - SSL Enabled : True
      - SSL URL : https://localhost:44301/
      - URL : http://localhost:4800/
      - Windows Authentication : Disabled
    - Web :

      - Servers :

        - Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)
        - IIS Express
        - Project Url : http://localhost:4800/
- Project : Espace.MockWS

  - Properties :

    - Development Server :

      - Always Start When Debugging : True
      - Anonymous Authentication : Disabled
      - Managed Pipeline Mode : Integrated
      - SSL Enabled : False
      - URL : http://localhost:6504/
      - Windows Authentication : Disabled
    - Web :

      - Servers :

        - Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)
        - IIS Express
        - Project Url : http://localhost:6504/
- Project : Espace.Switcher

  - Properties :

    - Development Server :

      - Always Start When Debugging : True
      - Anonymous Authentication : Disabled
      - Managed Pipeline Mode : Integrated
      - SSL Enabled : False
      - URL : http://localhost:57585/
      - Windows Authentication : Disabled
    - Web

      - Servers

        - Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)
        - IIS Express
        - Project Url : http://localhost:57585/
- Project : Espace.WebControls

  - Properties

    - Development Server

      - Always Start When Debugging : True
      - Anonymous Authentication : Disabled
      - Managed Pipeline Mode : Integrated
      - SSL Enabled : False
      - URL : http://localhost:57579/
      - Windows Authentication : Disabled
    - Web

      - Servers

        - Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)
        - IIS Express
        - Project Url : http://localhost:57579/

The following page is loaded in Internet Explorer after I start debugging on my computer (OS : Windows 7) : http://localhost:4800/TestFiles/Authentication.aspx.
But the page is not loaded after I start debugging on another computer (OS : Windows 8).
No error message is displayed but Internet Explorer keeps on waiting.
I have inserted a breakpoint in the Page_Load method but it is not reached.

Here are the sites started in IIS Express on my computer after I start debugging :

```
Site Name           URL                         PID
Espace.MockWS       http://localhost:6504/      3416
Espace.WebControls  http://localhost:57579/     848
Espace.Switcher     http://localhost:57585/     6676
Espace              http://localhost:4800/      3752
Espace              https://localhost:44301/    3752
```

Here is the only site started in IIS Express on the other computer after I start debugging :

```
Site Name           URL                         PID
Espace              https://localhost:44301/    11480
```

I guess the page is not loaded on the other computer because the four HTTP sites are not started.
Does anyone know why ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

On the other computer, you have to copy over your config file in `My Documents\IIS Express\config`.

This is required by VS2013 while VS2015 stores it in the solution folder.

Comment: I have replaced the config folder on the other computer with the config folder of my computer but it has not resolved the issue.

Comment: @user1139666 then you can check if the project file matches IIS Express config file, https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/11/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration/

Comment: I have not found any mismatch between the ".csproj" file of the project Espace and the "applicationhost.config" file of IIS Express.